# How to fix this DEPRECATION error in codeception?

Tags: codeception

I am using codeception,when I try to check dbconnection it shows the error:

```
> DEPRECATION: Calling the
> "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface::dispatch()"
> method with the event name as first argument is deprecated since
> Symfony 4.3, pass it second and provide the event object first
> instead.
> C:\xampp\htdocs\affiliate_codeception\codeception\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:58"
```

How do I  fix this?

```
<?php 
class adminTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{
    /**
     * @var \UnitTester
     */
    protected $tester;

    protected function _before()
    {
    }

    protected function _after()
    {
    }

    // tests
    public function testSomeFeature()
    {

    }
    public function tryToTest(UnitTester $I)
    {
       $I->amConnectedToDatabase('testdb');
       //$I->seeInDatabase('users', ['name' => 'Davert', 'email' => 'davert@mail.com']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Don't enable symfony module in unit tests.

Comment: @Naktibalda do you have any more details on this?

Comment: There is a ticket for that: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/5532
If you want to get rid of warnings, set composer contraint to use Symfony 4.2

Comment: @Naktibalda it seems like "Don't use any external libraries anywhere" (

Comment: @frops actually this library is used by Codeception itself and Codeception tries to support as wide range of versions as possible, but it looks like it won't be possible to support Symfony 5, and Symfony <4.3 in the same codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in vendor`/codeception/phpunit-wrapper/src/Listener.php`:

**Search for**

```
 dispatcher->dispatch(
```

For each of them, swap the first and second arguments.

***For example***, the first occurrence is:

```
 public function startTestSuite(\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite $suite)
 {
     $this->dispatcher->dispatch('suite.start', new SuiteEvent($suite));
 }
```

**Change it to:**

```
 public function startTestSuite(\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite $suite)
 {
     $this->dispatcher->dispatch(new SuiteEvent($suite), 'suite.start');
 }
```